# jQuery: Select all p elements with some attribute set

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I'm in the need for a jquery selector to get all p elements that has some attribute set, no matter the value and no matter the attribute name.

XPath related expression is:

```
"//p[@*]"
```

Comment: Elements have attributes that aren't necessarily in the source...what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I was trying to get <p> elements that have at least one inline attribute set as [@user113716](http://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/user113716) corrected. Sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're saying that you want `<p>` elements that have at least one inline attribute set, you could do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZRPv4/

```
var pWithAttrs = $('p').filter(function() {
    return this.attributes.length;
});
```

This will give you a set of `<p>` elements that have at least one inline attribute set.

It tests the `length` property of the `attributes` array associated with the current `<p>` in the iteration. If the `length` is `0`, it will be removed from the result.

---

Here's a custom selector version:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZRPv4/1/

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
   'hasAnAttr': function(elem, i, attr){      
     return elem.attributes.length;
   }
});

var pWithAttrs = $('p:hasAnAttr');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must build the selector string as follows:

If you have an array of attribute names and values `attrs`:

```
var selector = 'p';
for (var attrName in attrs) {
        selector = selector + '[' + attrName + '=' + attrs[attrName] + ']';
    }
}
```

This will create a selector string of the form:

```
p[attrName0=attrValue0][attrName1=attrName1] ...
```

and then use that selector in a jQuery statement:

```
$(selector).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that using expressions, but you can loop through the p elements and check for those that have attributes:

```
$('p').each(function(){
if(this.attributes.length > 0)
{
...do code...
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p").each(function(){
   if(this.attributes.size>0){

   }
});
```

I dont know if is exist a pure jquery solution.